# Are the 2015 Academy Nominated Animated Shorts family friendly?

Tags: animation, content-rating, academy-awards

The [2015 Academy Nominated Animated Shorts](http://seattletimes.com/html/entertainment/2025573683_oscarshortsxml.html?syndication=rss) are making the rounds in theaters right now. I can't find any specific information on the age appropriateness of the content.

Does anyone know if this is family friendly? I realize that's a subjective question so perhaps a better thing to ask is if anyone knows if there are any particular parts of the series that could be seen as not kid friendly to some people?

The following shorts were nominated:

- A Single Life
- The Dam Keeper
- Feast
- Me and My Moulton
- The Bigger Picture

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my thoughts on the Animated shorts:

**TL;DR : Content is probably fine... better with 10+ probably?**

Minor spoilers below.

- *Me and My Moulton* - About a kid. If you're extremely puritanical, there's a short sequence of nude, animated, barely anatomical male and female bodies... and a granny in underwear.  Non-sexual. There's also a brief moment of gun violence.

[image: Nudity in *Me and My Moulton*]

- *Feast* - About a guy, his dog, and the lady in their life, told through the dog's dinner bowl. Disney. Nothing here.
- *The Bigger Picture* - About two sons caring for their aging mother. Real life situations that aren't particularly pleasant but no violence or nudity.
- *A Single Life* - A woman going through various parts of her life. Nothing here. (really funny, though and only 2 minutes long!)
- *The Dam Keeper* - A pig who lives on the dam for their town is teased by his school peers. Major themes in this one are about bullying... probably actually good for a kid to see, provided parents are willing to discuss with the kid.

Where I saw the shorts, they included four additional shorts. They were all fine, too.

- *Sweet Cocoon* - A caterpillar needs some help getting into her cocoon. Animated bugs. Very French.
- *Footprints* - A man is woken in the night and follows footprints to figure out who broke his window. Contains a shotgun and some gunfire.
- *Duet* - A boy and girl growing up through life's various stages. Nothing here.
- *Bus Story* - A woman wants to be a school bus driver and this follows her first year doing it. Mild, accidental animal violence.